# Cloud Storage for Firebase bandwidth quota exceeded after downloading multiple images – what are the best practices?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm building an iOS app with data stored in Firestore and associated images stored in Cloud Storage for Firebase. Essentially, my app's starting screen is a scrolling list of cards representing documents from one of my Firestore collections and an associated image (pulled from Cloud Storage, matched using document title).

To generate the starting scrollview data, each time I open my app, I run a call to both Firestore and Cloud Storage to populate my local structs and retrieve the images (around 10 of them, each 600px by 400 px and between 300-500 KB).

I'm currently on the free Spark plan. My quotas are fine for Firestore, but yesterday, I was testing the app in the simulator (maybe ran it ~60 times?) and exceeded the 1 GB bandwidth limit for Cloud Storage calls. I think this is because I'm downloading a lot of images and not storing them locally (because I download them again each time the app is run?).

Here's the code that runs each time the app is opened to get all of the data and associated images:

```
//  StoryRepository.swift

import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class StoryRepository: ObservableObject { // listen to any updates
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    
    @Published var stories = [Story]() // Story is a local struct with vars for title, previewImage (the associated card image I get from Cloud Storage), and other data in Firestore. 
    
    init() {
        loadStoryCardData()
    }
    
    func loadStoryCardData() {
        db.collection("stories").addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            
            // create Cloud Storage reference
            let storageRef = self.storage.reference()
            
            // each document represents a story. get the title of that story, and then fetch the image from Cloud Storage that has the same filename as that title.
            documents.forEach { document in
                guard let title = document["title"] as? String else {
                    print("Could not read story title.")
                    return
                }
                
                let primaryImageRef = storageRef.child("storyCardPrimaryImages/" + title + ".jpg")

                // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
                primaryImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching primary image: \(error)")
                        return
                    } else {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                            self.stories.append(Story(title: title, previewImage: image, data: document.data())!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering how to optimize this, because when I release this app and gain users, I can just imagine where my bandwidth will go. Should I store the local structs and images in the iOS FileManager so I only download them once, when the app first runs? How will I update the local data should anything in either Firestore or Cloud Storage change?

I thought about storing the images in a smaller size, but I really need them to be 600px by 400px in my app. I'd prefer to stay on the free Spark plan if possible. Honestly, I'm just a little taken aback that I've already run into quota limits while testing – when it's just me running the app. Overall, I'm at a bit of a loss – any advice would be really, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I store the local structs and images in the iOS FileManager so I only download them once, when the app first runs?

Using a local cache like this is definitely one good way to reduce the total bandwidth use.

> How will I update the local data should anything in either Firestore or Cloud Storage change?

That will be for you to engineer.  In general, one way to do this would be for your process that updates the objects in storage to also update some metadata about the image, and store that in Firestore.  Your app can query Firestore, for changes, then check to see if your locally cached files are up to date before downloading them again.

> I thought about storing the images in a smaller size, but I really need them to be 600px by 400px in my app.

You can always increase the amount of JPG compression, which will also reduce the quality of the image.  That's a tradeoff you'll have to experiment with to your preference.